# Confused on the X11 Window system and what do I need to get it to work

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, gui, x11-forwarding

So in order to open a graphical interface in linux when doing `ssh` to a remote server we use the `X` system. Ok.
I have seen in some examples using `Putty` that there is some configuration on `Putty` client, basically a check-box to enable `X-11`.
My question is: I am using the `Mac's` default `Terminal` console to do `ssh`.
In this case is:
1) Is `ssh -X` the equivalent to what `Putty` offers as configuration in order to enable `X11`?
2) Is `X11` installed by default in a `Mac`? I mean I am confused on the following: when in my `Mac` open the `Terminal` and do: `ssh hostname` to login to a linux system, the `X-11` must be installed in `Mac`, right? Is this installed by default? How would I know?
I have been reading about these but I am still confused on the matter.
For instance if I want to run `Eclipse` for source code residing in the remote server, I would need to copy `Eclipse` in a directory on the remote server and start Eclipse and if the `X11` is correctly set up, I should be able to see the UI. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

1. You have number one backward; but yes, X11 is what Putty emulates.
2. You need to install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) on current versions of OS X. It is no longer part of a default install.

Once you have XQuartz, you could `ssh -X user@host` or `ssh -Y user@host` for X forwarding.

Comment: +1. So `XQuartz` is the only way to open a `GUI` on a remote server we ssh to, or are there other ways as well?

Comment: XQuartz adds X11 support to OS X. If your server isn't OS X, it would have X11 through a different means (and if it's linux, it is probably there by default).

Comment: My server isn't `OSX`. My computer that I `ssh` to this `linux` server is `OSX`. So do I need `XQuartz` or not? I am confused now.

Comment: X11 has to be on *both* server and client. As your client side is `OS X`, you do need `XQuarts` (on your mac). Sorry if my previous comment confused you.

Comment: Perfectly clear.One last question.Why is `XQuartz` no longer installed by default?Is it a security hole for example?

Comment: I've heard of one or two ways to attack a poorly configured X11 instance. But I would speculate it is more to save space by not including something that a large portion of their user base will never use (like how they don't include `make`, unless you install a sub package of xcode)

Comment: Really?I thought that people that bought `Mac` would be "educated" users so connecting to a remote server via `ssh` would actually be something that their user base would need. But I don't know much about `Mac`

Comment: @demure, no X11 does not have to be on the server for the client side X support. For example, on my remote server I only installed xterm, and of course the despondence for xterm. and was able to start server xterm in my local X. I.e., I didn't install X11/Xorg on my remote server for it to work.

Comment: @xpt was that manually, or with a package manager? I was sure it was a dependency as well.

Comment: @demure, this is what xterm depends under Ubuntu, the server that I'm using: xbitmaps, libc6 (>= 2.15), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.8.0), libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0), libtinfo5, libutempter0 (>= 1.1.5), libx11-6, libxaw7, libxft2 (>> 2.1.1), libxmu6, libxt6. I.e., libx11 is enough, no need the whole x11 package.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run something like eclipse on the remote machine, you will want to be able to re-connect to the session in case the network drops. If you used "ssh -X", the session would crash instead.
For that, you need something like [Xpra](http://xpra.org/) or NX. Which will also give you much better performance than plain X11 or SSH-X11.

Comment: just to note that nx4 dosen't have the screen-style separated sessions that persist even if the user is not logged into the main system - it works like VNC and shows the session running on the system at that point of time